# USB Internet Connection Sharing disconnects after updating to macos 12.7.3

Tags: macos, network, usb, bug, tethering

I have been using USB Internet Connection from my Macbook Pro for some years, fairly reliably. We rely upon it since we are a Wifi free house. After updating to macos 12.7.3 Monterey, both iPhones disconnected. After taking various steps, I've managed to get a temporary connection (maybe an hour). Steps taken below:

- Tried turning things on/off.
  [image]
- I deleted the contents of </Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration>, except for 'com.apple.Boot.plist', since it was a locked file. Some article recommended deleting the contents of this folder to reset network settings. Doing this resets the Network pane in Settings to defaults.[image]
- Resetted SMC & NVRAM. Resetted network settings in iPhones. Causing a 'trust' screen which I authorised.

***This 'System Information' pane shows the problem. Shouldn't there be only one iPhone active service with one IP (1 iPhone connected)?? The IP address range 169.254.x.x could mean there is a problem, being not allocated by a DHCP server. After taking all the above steps, this still comes back!***[image]

*I would really appreciate some help with this (preferably from an Apple software engineer). Are the ghost iPhone's causing the problem? This hasn't happened before after updating.*

Thankyou for your time.